# Java time expiring List/Set?

Tags: java, list, set

I've been looking around for a Java list, set, or something similar that has entries expire after a given time period, but I have yet to find one. I've found Guava's [`CacheBuilder`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), which would be almost perfect for my use, but that it is a map rather than a List or Set. Is there already something out there like this, or will I have to make one if I want to use it?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing a use case as well.  Typically when you want to cache things, you need a key to retrieve what's being cached, hence why every cache implementation works with the Map interface (or something similar).

Comment: you can still iterate over the Set

Comment: I'm making an anti-repeat message plugin for a chatroom where users talk. I use a map to link the user to a list of messages that I check the new message against. I want to only store 5 messages in any one user's list(already completed), and have any stored messages that are over x units of time old expire.

Comment: Another use case is to get the number of requests received in a server in the past 1 hour

Answer (score 13):

To use `CacheBuilder` to get a time expired list, you could put your objects in the map as keys and some dummy object as values.

Comment: Or use your objects as key and value. Just take care not to create a new object for each dummy, as that would be waste.

Answer (score 3):

You could decorate a collection implementation to do that. Something like this:

```java
public class ExpirableArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private final Date creation = new Date();

    private final long timeToLiveInMs;

    public ExpirableArrayList(long timeToLiveInMs, int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
        this.timeToLiveInMs = timeToLiveInMs;
    }

    public ExpirableArrayList(long timeToLiveInMs) {
        this.timeToLiveInMs = timeToLiveInMs;
    }

    public ExpirableArrayList(long timeToLiveInMs, Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
        this.timeToLiveInMs = timeToLiveInMs;
    }

    private void expire() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - creation.getTime() > timeToLiveInMs) {
            clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        expire();
        return super.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        expire();
        return super.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        expire();
        return super.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        expire();
        return super.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        expire();
        return super.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        expire();
        return super.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        expire();
        return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        expire();
        return super.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        expire();
        return super.contains(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        expire();
        return super.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
        expire();
        return super.addAll(index, c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        expire();
        return super.removeAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        expire();
        return super.retainAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        expire();
        return super.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        expire();
        return super.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public E remove(int index) {
        expire();
        return super.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        expire();
        return indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        expire();
        return lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        expire();
        return listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
        expire();
        return listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        expire();
        return subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the intention. Each entry should have its own timestamp.

Comment: So you should use a map.

Comment: No. It's like a set where the entry is no longer present once the time has passed.
Of course, you can get the same behaviour with a guava cache map where the value is some dummy value like the key itself or boolean.

Answer (score 2):

The missing piece here is the function `Collections#newSetFromMap`. This is *exactly* what you need to use Guava's `CacheBuilder` with all its features. For instance, to create a set whose objects expire after a minute, you could use:

```java
Set<String> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).<String, Boolean>build().asMap());
```

You need to use `Boolean` as the dummy value type here, as `Collections#newSetFromMap` expects a `Map<E, Boolean>`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Java HashSet implementation uses internally a HashMap, it should be really easy to copy/modify the code so that it uses Guavas CacheBuilder.

```
public class HashSet<E>
    extends AbstractSet<E>
    implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    static final long serialVersionUID = -5024744406713321676L;

    private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;
...
```

In other words, just implement your `SetWithExpiration` as a `CacheBuilder` map from key to key.  This will lose no more efficiency than the Java `HashSet` implementation loses by using an underlying `HashMap`.

Comment: Not so simple. Re-inventing the `HashSet` class is a bad idea, and you can't just "make HashSet use a CacheBuilder instead"

Comment: yes, the clean code solution would be to extend AbstractSet and use internally a Map which is passed by dependecy injection.